# What is the effect of sudo apt-get install atfs?

Tags: apt

I accidentally execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install atfs
```

and my friend said i should install again this package:https://packages.debian.org/sid/libatfs1. What are the effects in our web server? Should i install what my friend suggested? So far, there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

`libatfs1` is a dependency of [`atfs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/atfs), so it should already be installed. Also tell your friend to be careful about the source of the package - that's a link to the version in Debian `sid` (experimental quality).

Comment: So no need to install the suggested package. After installing atfs i have seen this process in terminal..please see this link http://tinypic.com/r/s1uqs6/8...And tell me if there is something wrong.